# JavaScript/CoffeeScript for a whole namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where do I put a javascript code that applies to everything included in the namespace?
e.g. i have:

```
- javacripts
    - application.js
    - admin
        - users.js.coffee
        - posts.js.coffee
```

Now where should a code for both posts and users go?

Comment: That is you personal choice. However, if you wish you could create some folder called common and put other stuffs there to properly manage things.

Comment: You can create `common.js` in under `javascripts` folder directly, and include in `application.js`.